# Whats the proper way to import "Dynamic" components with Next JS? (Wordpress Flexible Content)

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, next.js, headless

I am new to NextJS and I am struggling to figure out the proper way of doing this. For this example I am trying to use WordPress and ACF's Flexible Content module as a page builder of sorts.

On my index.js I am using getStaticProps and GraphQL query to check what Flexible Content modules are selected in WordPress, and would like to then turn each of those modules into a component.

I tried using the code below to loop through my module names and then import it as a component but it keeps throwing out an error "Unexpected token `)`. Expected this, import, async, function, [ for array literal, { for object literal, @ for decorator, function, class, null, true, false, number, bigint, string, regexp, `
| for template literal, (, or an identifier"

I am also not 100% if using "dynamic" is the correct way to do this, its just what I found as I researched how to do this.

```
  return (
    <Layout>
      <WebsiteJsonLd siteTitle={title} />
      <>
      {flexible.map( layout => {
          let layoutName = layout['__typename'].replace('Page_Acf_Flexiblecontent_', '');
          let FlexLayout = dynamic(() => import(''+layoutName));
          return (
              <h1>{layoutName}</h1>
              <FlexLayout />
          )
      })}
      </>
    </Layout>
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it! The code above actually works for the most part, it was just that the include path was incorrect. Changing it to `mport(''+layoutName));` did the trick.

I ended up not using this in the end though. Dynamic imports are not rendered server side so this is not great for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

From the Next.js [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#example):

> **In import('path/to/component'), the path must be explicitly written. It can't be a template string nor a variable**. Furthermore the import() has to be inside the dynamic() call for Next.js to be able to match webpack bundles / module ids to the specific dynamic() call and preload them before rendering. **dynamic() can't be used inside of React rendering as it needs to be marked in the top level of the module for preloading to work, similar to React.lazy**.

This means that:

```
let FlexLayout = dynamic(() => import(''+layoutName));
```

inside your component is an invalid statement. You can only dynamically import modules statically.

Comment: I've read this, however I have seen various posts here on stack overflow about getting around that. Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62942727/dynamic-importing-of-an-unknown-component-nextjs)

Comment: @AlexKinejara Even if that would work, the dynamic import needs to be done outside React rendering, at the top level of the module.

Comment: @juliomalves i actually got it working almost as is, the issue was just the path. I had to add './' in the import quotes.