# How to catch dynamic import error in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm using Next.js to develop a website.

I want to use dynamic import `import()` to dynamically load a module. It might not exist.

And if it does not exist, I'm OK with supressing it:

```
const Blog = async () => {

    let Layout = <div>Fallback layout</div>
    try {
        const { ModuleLayout } = await import('path-to-module').catch(reason => {})
        if (ModuleLayout) {
            Layout = ModuleLayout
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        // intentionally swallawed
    }

    return <Layout />
}
```

I would expect the `try-catch` statement to suppress the error for me.

But I get this error:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'path-to-module'

Why the `catch` block does not work? How can I catch the error of dynamic import?

Comment: Does the `<Layout />` render?

Comment: Nope, because Next.js shows the error instead of rendering.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/62942727/2715716

Answer (score 4):

The `try`-`catch` works with normal JavaScript in both the browser and Node:

```html
  try {
    const { ModuleLayout } = await import('path-to-module').catch(reason => { })
    if (ModuleLayout) {
      console.log(ModuleLayout);
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log('error');
  }
```

BTW the `.catch` there is redundant.

I think the problem here is that Next does extra analysis on imports through WebPack:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6680#issuecomment-370800037

The suggestion here is to constrain the path to a known directory, but that might not be applicable in your case. Maybe your usecase would make for a good issue on the Next repository so that Vercel is motivated to add a flag to disable the static analysis for certain imports.

Documentation about dynamic import in Next:
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#example

> Note: In `import('path/to/component')`, the path must be explicitly written. It can't be a template string nor a variable. Furthermore the `import()` has to be inside the `dynamic()` call for Next.js to be able to match webpack bundles / module ids to the specific `dynamic()` call and preload them before rendering. `dynamic()` can't be used inside of React rendering as it needs to be marked in the top level of the module for preloading to work, similar to `React.lazy`.

No hint on how to work around this and get a truly dynamic export at runtime.

Someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71659583/2715716) claims warapping the `import` in `dynamic` did the trick for them.