# Why am I not seeing route attributes on my simple Next.js route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js

I'm trying to create a simple routing test in a Next.js application using [Dynamic Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)

As part of my test I have created `pages/test/[id].js` with the following code:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function Test() {
    const router = useRouter()
    console.log(router)
    return <p />
}
```

However, when hitting the URL `test/foo?a=1` I see the following in console:

```js
ServerRouter {
  route: '/test/[id]',
  pathname: '/test/[id]',
  query: {},
  asPath: '/test/[id]',
  basePath: '',
  events: undefined,
  isFallback: false,
  locale: undefined,
  isReady: false,
  locales: undefined,
  defaultLocale: undefined,
  domainLocales: undefined,
  isPreview: false,
  isLocaleDomain: false
}
```

Question is, I'm expecting to see something here, particularly in `query`.  What's missing here?

Comment: Might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61040790/userouter-withrouter-receive-undefined-on-query-in-first-render)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your router to be ready (after page loaded) before trying to console log it.

You could wrap your `console.log(router)` inside a useEffect to prevent this behavior or even better, wait for it to be ready via, `router.isReady`  inside your `useEffect` before trying to log it.

A recommandation I would have when trying to observe any kind of data (state, query...) is to wrap your `console.log` inside a useEffect instead of using it directly at top level.

If you want to log the router for example, each time it changes, you could put router inside brackets at the end of your useEffect, this will re-run what's inside your useEffect each time the value of router (or anything you want to put in there) changes!

Like this,

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(router)
}
,[router])
```