# Next.js useRouter() not returning variable inside useEffect()

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to return useRouter() variable inside useEffect().But unable to get it. getting undefined error inside the console. I actually fetching the data from API on the basis of the slug.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'; 
import axios from "axios";
const Post = () => {
const router = useRouter();
const [snippets,SetSnippets] = useState();
const { snippet_slug } = router.query;

var config = {
headers: {
    accept: '*/*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'API_ACCESS_KEY': 'hns2V0Ddbkkn8r1XLq3Kw7ZoiBTR0nmA',
}
};    
const url = 'api/viewsnippets';
useEffect(async ()=>{
var data = {
  slug: snippet_slug,
} 
console.log(snippet_slug); // Here i am getting error(i.e undefined)  
await axios.post(url,data,config)
.then(function (response) {
SetSnippets(response.data);
});
},[]);

return (
  <>
  {snippets && (
    <h1>{snippets.snippet_title}</h1>
  )}
  </>
);
}
export default Post;
```

Comment: do you have snippet_slug in your url query params ?
eg: [domain]/path?snippet_slug="somevalue"

Comment: I used POST method here

Comment: I mean your page url... router.query contains snippet_slug only if your page url
is containing snippet_slug in query params
eg: [domain]/path?snippet_slug="somevalue"

Comment: Yes URL contains -> [domain]/path?snippet_slug="somevalue". Everything is fine on api side. I tested it on POSTMAN.  Problem is I am not able to get snippet_slug inside useEffect. Might be useEffect loading before useRouter

Comment: Yes, useEffect loading before useRouter. Check the answer below.

Comment: @Gucal what should i do?

Comment: I left an answer below. Can you try it? This is how I mostly solve this problem. But I don't know if it's best practice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useRouter/withRouter receive undefined on query in first render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61040790/userouter-withrouter-receive-undefined-on-query-in-first-render)

Answer (score 3):

Following Code Solved My problem... Thanks all for reply

```
useEffect(async ()=>{
  if(!router.isReady) return;
  const { sid } = router.query;
var data = {
  slug: sid,
} 
console.log(sid);  
await axios.post(url,data,config)
.then(function (response) {
SetSnippets(response.data);
});

}, [router.isReady]);
```

Comment: This helped! Looks like `router` is not quite ready for the `useEffect` to use. `router.isReady` flag can be used to check if it is.

Answer (score 2):

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
```

import useRouter from **"next/navigation"** instead of "next/router". This line of import solved my problem.

Comment: Yes but why this is happening? Give us some more info pls

Comment: Next.js v13 introduced a new routing system called the `App Router`, which is built on top of Server Components and uses a different router hook than the traditional `Pages Router`.  You can spot a dropdown in the documentation page to switch between App router and Page router. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The error is here

`const { snippet_slug } = router.query;`

You have ended up renaming vs assigning the value via destructuring.

Use

`const snippet_slug = router.query;`

Returns an empty object on page load as defined by the docs if no querystring present , not an error

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-a2h28v?file=pages/index.js

https://nextjs-a2h28v--3000.local.webcontainer.io/?what=why - look at console

Review this post [https://www.barrymichaeldoyle.com/destructuring/#:~:text=A%20Common%20Pitfall%20and%20The%20Inspiration%20for%20this%20Post](https://www.barrymichaeldoyle.com/destructuring/#:%7E:text=A%20Common%20Pitfall%20and%20The%20Inspiration%20for%20this%20Post)