# Query lost on page refresh in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, query-string, server-side-rendering

`router.query.title` goes away when I refresh the page.

from what I found I have to use getServerSideProps but I don't know what to type on getServerSideProps. or is there any way to do it?

edit: I tried Yilmaz's solution and removed the as={} now it works. But query links too long now without using as={} any solution for this?

index.tsx

```
const Projects = () => {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState(data);

  {projects.slice(0, loadMore).map((project) => (
          <Link
            key={project.id}
            href={{
              pathname: "/projects/" + project.title,
              query: {
                id: project.id,
                category: project.category,
                title: project.title,
                image: project.image.src,
                image1: project.image1.src,
                image2: project.image2.src,
                image3: project.image3.src,
                image4: project.image4.src,
                image5: project.image5.src,
              },
            }}
            as={"/projects/" + project.title}
            passHref={true}
          >
}
```

[id].tsx

```
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  return {
    props: {},
  };
};

const Details = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <>
      <div className="single__page">
        <div className="single__header">
          <h2>{router.query.title}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: you can access the `query` object using `context.query`, in this case it will be `context.query.title` and then you can return it as a prop from `getServerSideProps`

Comment: You don't necessarily need to force `getServerSideProps` on the page. You can simply wait for `router.isReady` to be true. See [useRouter/withRouter receive undefined on query in first render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61040790/userouter-withrouter-receive-undefined-on-query-in-first-render).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
import { NextPageContext } from "next";


export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context: NextPageContext) => { {
      const { query } = context;
      return { props: { query } };
    }
```

this will pass `query` to props. When you hover over `query`, ts will already infer its type as: `const query: ParsedUrlQuery`

in your component

```
const Details = (props) => {
  // this is object
  const {query}=props
  console.log(query)

  return (
    <>
      <div className="single__page">
        <div className="single__header">
          <h2></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
```

- **Next 13 UPDATE**

If you set the experimental feature `appDir: true`, all the components in "app" directory will be server-side by default. Those components or pages have 2 default props

```
{ params: { slug: '2' }, searchParams: { title: 'new ' } }
```

you can access to query param as `props.searchParams.title`

### Second approach

```
const Details = () => {
  const [title,setTitle]=useState("")
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.isReady) {
      // Code using query
      console.log(router.query);
      // this will set the state before component is mounted
      setTitle(router.query.title)
    }
  }, [router.isReady]);

return (
    <>
      <div className="single__page">
        <div className="single__header">
          <h2>{title}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
     )
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help but what exactly should I type in "NextPageContext" and how should I pass into other components . i put {query} : any into details.tsx and still states goes away on the refresh.

Comment: @JuliaSchafer NextPageContext is type. updated the answer

Comment: @JuliaSchafer did you already set "title` query. what do you see when you console.log(query)

Comment: @JuliaSchafer can you test the second approach. updated the answer. witout serversideProps

Comment: can you run the app on a different browser?

Comment: restarted the server. tried on different browsers still same.. gıcık etti sabahtan beri :)

Comment: :) at least you could speak turkish now:)

Comment: Thank you! abi linke as=href eklemişim onu silince çalıştı teşekkürler :) şimdide query linki çok uzun oldu yav

Comment: I am new to Next js so, can someone please teach me basics of it

Comment: @Yilmaz I have a similar issue, if possible can you look into it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76773862/nextjs-how-to-pass-query-parameters-in-router-push-while-keeping-url-clean

Comment: @ransom have you tried the second solution?

Comment: @Yilmaz tried, no luck