# How can I pass query parameters in router.push while keeping URL clean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks

My project is in NextJS 13 (not using the app router) + TypeScript.

I'm trying to pass some data over router.push to the dynamic routed page in Next.js using the following syntax, but want the URL to remain clear, as the user can just edit their username in the URL otherwise.

```
router.push({
            pathname: `/editor/${roomId}`,
            query: { username: username, }
        }, `/editor/${roomId}`,
```

**PROBLEM**: The username does show when I get directed to /editor/roomid. **But when i refresh the page, it disappears**; the **username from `router.query` object just disappears**.
Relevant code:

`relevant code from JoinRoom.tsx`:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

interface JoinRoomProps { };

const JoinRoom = (props: JoinRoomProps) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [roomId, setRoomId] = useState('');
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [isGenerated, setIsGenerated] = useState(false);

    const generateRoomId = () => {
        setRoomId(nanoid());
        setIsGenerated(true);
    };

    const joinHandler = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!roomId || !username) {
            alert('Please fill in the required fields');
            return;
        }
        router.push({
            pathname: `/editor/${roomId}`,
            query: { username: username, }
        }, `/editor/${roomId}`,
        );
    };

    return (
        <>
            // input fields for roomid, username, join room (with joinHandler)
        </>
    );
};

export default JoinRoom;
```

`relevant code from [roomid].tsx`:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

interface RoomIDProps { };

const Editor = (props: RoomIDProps) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { roomid, username } = router.query;

    return (
        <> 
            // display roomid and username
        </>
    )
}

// idk exactly what the below functions do, copilot came up with them:
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    return {
        paths: [
            { params: { roomid: 'test' } }
        ],
        fallback: true
    }
}

export async function getStaticProps(context: any) {
    const { roomid } = context.params;
    return {
        props: {
            roomid
        }
    }
}

export default Editor;
```

how to fix this? Also, what do the last two functions of `[roomid].tsx` do? I've started playing around with Nextjs recently, so any related advice/better code practices would be helpful.

Comment: can you comment out `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` and try it?

Comment: @Yilmaz commented them out, no luck. After reload the `router.query` returns an object with just the roomid

Comment: can u create a repo, pls?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: @ZombieChowder I refactored to react.js instead of nextjs lol

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
 router.push({
        pathname: `/editor/${roomId}`,
        query: { username: username, }
    // remomve `/editor/${roomId}`
    // if you look at the URL, ?username=name was never added
    }, `/editor/${roomId}`,
```

to:

```
router.push({
      pathname: `/editor/${roomId}`,
      query: { username: username },
    });
```

this is `push` type

```
push(url: Url, as?: Url, options?: TransitionOptions): Promise<boolean>;
```

this is `Url` type

```
export type Url = UrlObject | string;
```

you were passing `UrlObject` and `string` at the same time

Comment: router.query does persist, but the problem was that username doesn't persist in router.query after reload, only roomid does

Comment: got it, but is there a way to keep the url clean? like i dont want to add the `?username=dobidias`, to the url, as the user can change it from the url and that change will be reflected on the page as well. that's why i used the alias `as`. for now, i'm using sessionstorage to store the username

Comment: next.js used to have `as` property in early versions but it is deprecated.