# Need router.query variable passed to API URL call, but is undefined on first render

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have the following API Call:

```
const router = useRouter();
const { albumQuery } = router.query;
const [albums, setAlbums] = useState([]);

const fetchAlbumsHandler = useCallback(async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    try {
      const url = `http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.search&album=${albumQuery}&api_key=MY_API_KEY&format=json`;
      const res = await fetch(url);
      const data = await res.json();

      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error("Something went wrong!");
      }

      const jsonAlbums = data.map(
      // JSON business Logic
      );

      setAlbums(transformedAlbums);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, []);
```

With the corresponding useEffect function:

```
useEffect(() => {
      fetchAlbumsHandler();
  }, [fetchAlbumsHandler]);
```

However, the API call takes `${albumQuery}` as undefined on the first render due to NextJS implementation details. Is there a way for me to access the variable on the first render?

Comment: No - as you say, it's undefined on the first render. But you can make your code wait until the second render before doing anything. A simple `albumQuery && fetchAlbumsHandler();` would suffice, no?

Comment: Why is the query not available on the initial render? If it isn't then the code needs to wait for when it is valid to make the GET request by checking if the `albumQuery` query value is available.

Comment: In Next.js, statically optimized pages are hydrated without query parameters. You'll have to use `router.isReady` to check/wait for the parameter to be available after hydration. See [useRouter/withRouter receive undefined on query in first render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61040790/userouter-withrouter-receive-undefined-on-query-in-first-render) and https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization#how-it-works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if the `albumQuery` isn't available on the initial render then the code should handle waiting for it to become available.

The existing code is assuming `albumQuery` is available on the initial render and attempts to close it over in the `useCallback` hook. After this the `useEffect` hook is called and since `fetchAlbumsHandler` is now a stable reference the `useEffect` hook won't be retriggered nor will `fetchAlbumsHandler` be re-memoized since the `useCallback` hook has an empty dependency array.

Minimally `albumQuery` appears to be a dependency for the `useCallback` hook and/or the `useEffect` hook. If `fetchAlbumsHandler` isn't passed as a prop to children there's no real benefit to memoizing it. I suggest moving it into the `useEffect` hook callback and using `albumQuery` as a dependency.

Example:

```
const router = useRouter();
const { albumQuery } = router.query;
const [albums, setAlbums] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchAlbumsHandler = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);

    try {
      const url = `http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.search&album=${albumQuery}&api_key=MY_API_KEY&format=json`;
      const res = await fetch(url);
      const data = await res.json();

      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error("Something went wrong!");
      }

      const jsonAlbums = data.map(
      // JSON business Logic
      );

      setAlbums(transformedAlbums);
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  }

  fetchAlbumsHandler();
}, [albumQuery]);
```