# How to send request to server only when URL param is loaded? [ Next.JS ]

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios, react-query

In the Next.js I'm working,you can get a post in the route `/posts/[id].tsx` ,I am using react-query to make the get request.
I get the postId with

> const {id}=router.query

But everytime I enter the page it sends the request to the server with `undefined` ,and also, do you guys know how to disable the React property of sending twice the requests when we enter a page? I think it is a waste of processing (correct me if I'm wrong please)
Thank you for reading until here !!!

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, the value you get from `useRouter().query` is an empty object on the first render. The router also exposes an [isReady flag](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object) to indicate that the router is ready to use. You can combine this with the `enabled` option of react-query to defer the actual request:

```
const router = useRouter()
const { id } = router.query

useQuery({
  queryKey: ['my-query', id],
  queryFn: () => fetchMyQuery(id)
  enabled: router.isReady
})
```

you could also pass `Boolean(id)` or `!!id` to `enabled` to just disable the query when you have no id for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can use useEffect to check if the id is available, then run the rest of your code.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!id) return;
    console.log(id);
}, [id]);
```

If reactStrictMode in the next.config.js file is set to true, it will run your code twice. This is only in development mode.

Answer (score 1):

to extract the value we can use a hook called useRouter from next/router.
if we have a file called [newsId].tsx , we can get newsId value in the following manner.

```
//[newsId].tsx
import {useRouter} from 'next/router

function DetailPage(){
const router = useRouter();

//gives us the value in url

console.log(router.query.newsId;)

return <h1>hello</h1>
}
export default DetailPage
```

note that the double values where one is undefined is because the component is loaded initially without the value then again when it gets the value. If you want it to render once you can refer to this answer. [useRouter/withRouter receive undefined on query in first render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61040790/userouter-withrouter-receive-undefined-on-query-in-first-render)

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Would appreciate if you upvote the answer so it helps others too.

Comment: I would love a lot but right now I only have reputation 11 and it needs 15 to upvote