# how to set default page in next js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i am new in `next.js`, in `next.js` default page in `index.js`, i want to change its path as `login` , can anyone please help me how to do it ? right now i am using `Router.push('/login');`  but it is creating flickering issue, can anyone please help for this issue ?

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import Router from 'next/router'
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';


export default function Home(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const { pathname } = Router
    if (pathname == '/') {
      Router.push('/login');
    }
  }, [props]);

  return ''
}
```

Comment: have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173809/next-js-redirect-from-to-another-page

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can add [**`redirects`**](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects) to your **`next.config.js`** like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/about',
        destination: '/',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect from the server side;

```
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ res }) => {
    res.setHeader("location", `/kiosk/welcome`);

    res.statusCode = 302;
    res.end();

    return { props: {} };
};

const Index = () => <>Index</>;

export default Index;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can set a base path. Next Js allows you to do this. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath For example, if you wish to use "/login" instead of "/" which is the default, open next.config.js and add the basePath config:

```
  const nextConfig = {
  basePath: "/login",
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Comment: That way you added a prefix called "/login" for each route when using the Next Link component.