# Redirect page to url Next.JS

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, next.js

I have a simple web page running next.js, the page just returns the "Hello World" element and I would like it to redirect me to another URL (youtube) instead.

It is basically a redirect page when loading.

My simple page:

```
function Home() {
    return <div>Hello World</div>
}

export default Home
```

I even tried the js window.location function, but to no avail

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173809/next-js-redirect-from-to-another-page

Answer (score 7):

In `next.js` you can redirect **after the page is loaded** using `Router` ex :

```
import Router from 'next/router'

componentDidMount(){
    const {pathname} = Router
    if(pathname == '/' ){
       Router.push('/hello-nextjs')
    }
}
```

Or with Hooks :

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
...
useEffect(() => {
   const {pathname} = Router
   if(pathname == '/' ){
       Router.push('/hello-nextjs')
   }
 });
```

Comment: I'd recommend using `useRouter` instead for the hooks approach.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the page to redirect while server-side rendering, you can put this at the bottom of your export function in your /pages/file and set an if conditional.

So for example, if that page doesn't exist, it will redirect to something else.

This way you don't have to play around with `route.push`.

```
if (!pageData) {
    res.statusCode = 301;
    res.setHeader("location", "/page-you-want-to-redirect-to");
    res.end();
    return {props: {notFound: true}};
}

export default Page
```

Thanks