# How to push user to external (incomplete) URL. i.e google.com NEXTJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

Im trying to push a user to an external url but that problem is that the url is incomplete, for example it may look like this:
`google.com`
If I used link or even just an  tag in Nextjs, it will only link the user to an internal page. I want the user to be redirected to an external page. Here is my Code:

```
<a href={`${data.link}`}>
    <div className={css.visitLinkContainer}>
        Visit Link
    </div>
</a>
```

The `data.link` may have a url that is incomplete like this: `google.com`. How can I go around this problem?

Comment: Have you checked on here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173809/next-js-redirect-from-to-another-page

Comment: hello, im trying to redirect users to an external site, this forum only talks about internal pages, thanks anyway

Comment: You could consider using nextjs-redirect libray ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-redirect )

Comment: That might be what i need. I’ll let you know. Thanks

Comment: Are the URLs always external and incomplete? You could parse them and prepend `https://` to the URLs that need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, browsers use [relative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#absolute_urls_vs_relative_urls) URLs.  You can tell the browser to use an [implicit protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#examples_of_absolute_urls) by prepending `//`.

```js
<a href={`//${data.link}`}>Visit Link</a>
```

If some of your URLs can contain the [protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#scheme) (http[s]) you will need to remove it first.

```js
const href = new URL(data.link).host;
<a href={`//${href}`}>Visit Link</a>
```

Additional considerations when linking to external domains - if you link to an external domain and use `target="_blank"` you should also set `rel="noreferrer"` to [protect your user's privacy and increase site security](https://web.dev/external-anchors-use-rel-noopener/).

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [nextjs-redirect libray](http://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-redirect)