# Next JS Static Site: Redirect specific routes to another site?

Tags: next.js, amazon-cloudfront

I've made a static site using Next JS that is deployed on cloudfront. I'd like to have some routes redirect to another site by just changing the base path (e.g if the route is [www.mysite.com/stuff](http://www.mysite.com/stuff), it will redirect to [www.redirectedSite.com/stuff](http://www.redirectedSite.com/stuff)). Is this possible and if so, what would I use to set this up?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Next.js Redirect from / to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64198299/1870780)? You can use [`redirects`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects) to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `getStaticProps` function, there is an option to return a redirect value. This allows for redirecting to internal and external resources.

You could have the code below saved under `pages/stuff.tsx`. When a request is made to `/stuff`, they will be redirected.

```
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next';

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  return {
    redirect: {
      destination: 'http://www.redirectedsite.com/stuff',
      permanent: false,
    },
  };
};

const TestPage = (): JSX.Element => {
  return <div></div>;
};

export default TestPage;
```

[Next JS Documentation on `getStaticProps` redirect](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation)

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you very much for finding this! This solved my issue!