# How to redirect from domain to another domain in Next.js v13 app on server side behind proxy

Tags: docker, redirect, next.js, proxy, middleware

I do have many domains and I want to redirect them to one main domain.

List of domains:

- `example.com`
- `example1.com`
- `example2.com`
- `example3.com`

The main domain I want to redirect from other domains is `example.com`

There is a great answer to redirect Next.js on the server side to a different path.

> **Next.js >= 12** Now you can do redirects using middleware, create a _middleware.js file inside the pages folder (or any sub folder inside pages)
>
> ```js
> import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from 'next/server'
> export async function middleware(req, ev) {
>     const { pathname } = req.nextUrl
>     if (pathname == '/') {
>         return NextResponse.redirect('/hello-nextjs')
>     }
>     return NextResponse.next() }
> ```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58182678/10826693

**Note:** For Next.js v13, you must create the `middleware.js` file in the root directory of Next.js instead of `pages/_middleware.js` as mentioned in that answer.

If I try to redirect to another domain, the TypeScript code in middleware.ts in the root looks like this:

```js
/* eslint-disable @next/next/no-server-import-in-page */
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    const url = req.nextUrl.clone()
    console.log(url.host) //logs localhost:3000

    if (!url.host.match(/example.com/)) {
        url.host = 'example.com'
        return NextResponse.redirect(url) //never executes because the URL is always localhost in the Docker container
    }
    return NextResponse.next()
}
```

However, a Next.js v13 application running in a Docker container behind a proxy server always has the `localhost` URL in the host. And `url.host` in a Docker container always equals the URL localhost with a defined port inside the container (e.g. `localhost:3000`).

**How to redirect the domains `example1.com`, `example2.com` and `example3.com` to `example.com` including the same path, query parameters and hash when I only have `localhost` on the server side?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to redirect all domains in the Docker container to the master domain, you need to get the redirected URL from the `X-Forwarded-Host` header.

In addition to the host, you must also set the correct port (80/443 - header called `X-Forwarded-Port`) and protocol (http/https - header called `X-Forwarded-Proto`).

**Next.js v13** Create the `middleware.ts` file in your app's `src` folder and redirect all domains that do not match the `example.com` domain to it in production.

```js
/* eslint-disable @next/next/no-server-import-in-page */
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const url = request.nextUrl.clone();

  const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' // redirect only in production
  const requestedHost = request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-Host');

  if (isProduction && requestedHost && !requestedHost.match(/example.com/)) {
    const host = `example.com`; // set your main domain

    const requestedPort = request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-Port');
    const requestedProto = request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-Proto');

    url.host = host;
    url.protocol = requestedProto || url.protocol;
    url.port = requestedPort || url.port;

    return NextResponse.redirect(url);
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  matcher: '/',
};
```

Now all domains `example1.com`, `example2.com` and `example3.com` are redirected to `example.com` including the same path, query parameters and hash.