# preventing flashing of page when redirecting

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, react-hooks, url-routing

I do have a verify page and status check page. I want to be able to check the user who logged in if his/her status is a boolean(string) in the cloud firestore. However, whenever the user is successfully logged in, it goes to the `("/")` or the dashboard of the page wherein it should be only seen by users who are authenticated and have both true fields in `isEmailVerified` and `isVerified` in the cloud firestore.

route.js

```
export function withProtected(Component) {
  return function withProtected(props) {
    const auth = useAuth();
    const router = useRouter();
    var isEmailVerified;
    var isAdminVerified;
    async function readData() {
      // getUuid is from useAuth() in my AuthService.js
      const docRef = doc(db, "admins", auth.getUuid);
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        isEmailVerified = docSnap.data()["isEmailVerified"];
        isAdminVerified = docSnap.data()["isVerified"];

        if (auth.getUuid && isEmailVerified == "false") {
          console.log("Verify Email Page Pushed!!!!");
          Router.push("/components/VerifyEmailPage");
          return <h1>GO TO VERIFY EMAIL PAGE</h1>;
        } else if (auth.getUuid && isAdminVerified == "false") {
          console.log("pushed!");
          Router.push("/components/AdminRequestStatus");
          return <h1>GO TO ADMIN STATUS CHECKER PAGE</h1>;
        }
      } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    }
    useEffect(() => {
      readData();
    }, []);

    return <Component auth={auth} {...props} />;
  };
}
```

and here is the import of my route.js file

```
import Router, { useRouter, asPath } from "next/router";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "../utilities/AuthService";
import { db } from "../utilities/firebase-config";
import { doc, getDoc, onSnapshot, query } from "firebase/firestore";
import AdminRequestStatus from "./AdminRequestStatus";
import VerifyEmailPage from "./VerifyEmailPage";
```

Here is the VerifyPage where should be redirected when the value of `isEmaiVerified` is still false, I wrapped the Page of the function that I created `withProtected`

```
import React from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import { withProtected } from "./route";
import Header from "./Header";

function VerifyEmailPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Verify Email Page</title>
      </Head>
      <Header></Header>
    </div>
  );
}

// I wrapped the VerifyEmailPage with the withProtected function 
// that I created..
export default withProtected(VerifyEmailPage);
```

I am relatively new with react.js and next.js so your insights and ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In Firestore, the boolean type is stored as a boolean value, not a string. So you should update your comparison to check against the boolean value `false` instead of the string "false".

Comment: Hi does your issue resolved ?

Comment: @RohitKharche Hello, I have not yet fixed it.

Comment: Instead of solving for flashing you can introduce a loading state with the initial state as false, and change this state to true, whenever you finish loading the data. example [**`snippet`**](https://codefile.io/f/IUq118rokigJpYVEhCJM)

Comment: Hi @RohitKharche, is it possible for you to post this as your answer so I could select it as accepted answer? it has solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next.js Redirect from / to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173809/next-js-redirect-from-to-another-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of solving for flashing while redirecting you can introduce a loading state with the initial state as true, and change this state to false, whenever you finish loading the data from the firestore query.

Here’s how you could do it:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Router from "next/router";
import { useAuth } from "../utilities/AuthService";

export function withProtected(Component) {
  return function withProtected(props) {
    const auth = useAuth();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    async function readData() {
      const docRef = doc(db, "admins", auth.getUuid);
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        const isEmailVerified = docSnap.data()["isEmailVerified"];
        const isAdminVerified = docSnap.data()["isVerified"];

        if (auth.getUuid && isEmailVerified === false) {
          Router.push("/components/VerifyEmailPage");
        } else if (auth.getUuid && isAdminVerified === false) {
          Router.push("/components/AdminRequestStatus");
        }
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
      setLoading(false);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      readData();
    }, []);

    if (loading) {
      return <h1>Loading...</h1>; //you can also create loading component
    }

    return <Component auth={auth} {...props} />;
  };
}
```

You can also use some Spinning Loading components to make it more clean.